# Template specialization with type conversion

Tags: c++, templates, gcc, clang, template-specialization

I have found this piece of bogus code (contrived example below):

```
template <int I, typename T>
struct foo
{
    static int bar()
    {
        return 1;
    }
};

template <std::size_t Index, typename T>
struct foo<Index, T*>
{
    static int bar()
    {
        return 2;
    }
};
```

Please note that specialization uses different type (by mistake). Surprisingly it compiles without any errors (or warnings) with both GCC 4.8.1 and Clang 3.4. But what is even more strange for GCC line `foo<0, int*>::bar()` results in `1`, but Clang gives `2`. What is going on? Is it still considered as a specialization by the standard?

Comment: The specialization size_t should be an error (int != size_t)

Comment: So both compilers are wrong? Sounds quite... improbable ;-)

Comment: Why do you guys think it's a specialization at all?

Comment: @ruslo It's probably me who is wrong. I missed a part of the code when reading the question.

Comment: I suspect : `std::size_t` and `int` may be treated as different types only in case of function parameter, not template parameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gcc is wrong, because you simply can't call this specialization.
Just remove primary template definition:

```
template <int I, typename T>
struct foo;

template <std::size_t Index>
struct foo<Index, int*> {
  static int bar() {
    return 2;
  }
};

int main() {
  std::cout << foo<std::size_t(0), int*>::bar() << std::endl; // nope, not work
  std::cout << foo<0, int*>::bar() << std::endl; // nope, not work
}
```

See live [example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c924da7e25661441). And [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/de61df0092b84e4e) code must report ambiguous partial specialization, but it's not (for gcc). Clang [report](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e696fb52983c4194) "ambiguous".

PS I argee, that this part is not covered enough by standard.

**update**

clang in this situation won't work with **enums**, [example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/39dab7587e216eee).

Comment: I am almost positive that it is a GCC bug, I will fill a bug report later on. Meanwhile I think I should accept your answer :-) And I will keep you posted

Answer (score 0):

The restrictions on partially specializing a class template on a non-type template argument 14.5.5 [temp.class.spec] paragraph 8 list the following restriction:

> A partially specialized non-type argument expression shall not involve a template parameter of the partial specialization except when the argument expression is a simple identifier.

The argument expression using a `size_t` involves a conversion to `int` (`size_t` is unsigned) and is, thus, not a simple identifier.

Comment: @ruslo: It sure looks like a simple identifier but actually is `int(Index)` which doesn't seem to be a simple identifier anymore.

Comment: @ruslo: that maybe true for the identifier but the restriction clearly talks about the expression and that has to become `int(Index)` as the type of the entity identified by the identifier is `std::size_t` which is guaranteed not to be `int`.